# How to read multi level xml using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have few xml files in the following format.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?-->
<details>
  <Classes>
    <class>5</class>
    <section>A</class>
  </Classes>
  <student>
    <firstname>Avijeet</firstname>
    <lastname>Roy</lastname>
    <roll>01</roll>
  </student>
  <student>
    <firstname>Saurav</firstname>
    <lastname>Das</lastname>
    <roll>02</roll>
  </student>
   <Classes>
    <class>10</class>
    <section>A</class>
  </Classes>
  <student>
    <firstname>Saumitra</firstname>
    <lastname>Bain</lastname>
    <roll>10</roll>
  </student>
  <student>
    <firstname>Tarun</firstname>
    <lastname>Sing</lastname>
    <roll>11</roll>
  </student>
</details>
```

Now I want a datagrid like an my asp.net page

```
Class   Section fname    lname  roll
5   A   Avijeet  Roy    01
5   A   Saurav   Das    02
10  A   Saumitra Bain   10
10  A   Tarun    Sing   11
```

I have searched a lot but couldnt find similar things. I am new in C#

Comment: Lets start from...what have you tried?

Comment: How exactly are the students assigned to the classes? XML is defined so that the order of elements does not matter. If the order of elements matters, what you have here is a text file that *looks* like XML, but is not valid XML.

Comment: @Mushariar You could let us know, what you've *searched a lot*....or things *similar* to what you'd like to see...

Comment: yes, re thorsten's comment, i can't see any linkage at all between the student and the class. how is this reflected?

Answer (score 6):

I donot think the xml you are having is in correct format for your requirement, it should be like this:

```
<details>
 <Classes>
      <Class>
        <class>5</class>
        <section>A</class>
        <student>
         <firstname>Avijeet</firstname>
         <lastname>Roy</lastname>
         <roll>01</roll>
       </student>
       <student>
        <firstname>Saurav</firstname>
        <lastname>Das</lastname>
        <roll>02</roll>
      </student>
      </Class>

       <Class>
        <class>10</class>
        <section>A</class>
        <student>
         <firstname>Saumitra</firstname>
         <lastname>Bain</lastname>
         <roll>10</roll>
       </student>
       <student>
        <firstname>Tarun</firstname>
        <lastname>Sing</lastname>
        <roll>11</roll>
      </student>
      </Class>
  </Classes> 
</details>
```

After this you can use LINQ to XML:

Eg.:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
IEnumerable<XElement> selectors = from elements in doc.Elements("details").Elements("Classes").Elements("Class")
                                  select elements;
```

Comment: kapil, that's certainly a good advance on what was presented +1

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but unfortunately my xml format is a correct one. cause its given by Central Bank. I will paste the original file itself.

Comment: Well, it may be syntactically correct, but it is not semantically correct. If Central Bank thinks that this file assigns students to classes, then they have no understanding of XML.

Comment: Thats why i have posted it here. that is there any way to follow the sequence and get the desired result. I badly need this. Mr. Kapil may i have your email. i'll send you the original file that i need to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a typed dataset that reflects the XML file's structure and load the data from the XML file. Then you could do data binding. Also, you could use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb387098.aspx).